# Sum the count if all other elements in the dictionary are the same

Tags: javascript

I have an array of dictionary as follows :

```
[{name:'v1', count:1}, {name:'v1', count:1}, {name:'v2', count:1}, {name:'v2', count:1}]
```

How can I add up these counts if the names are same and form a dictionary as follows:

```
[{name:'v1', count:2}, {name:'v2', count:2}]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution relying on [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.protype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const data = [{name:'v1', count:1}, {name:'v1', count:1}, {name:'v2', count:1}, {name:'v2', count:1}]

const result = Object.entries(data.reduce(
  (acc, { name, count }) => {
    acc[name] = count + (acc[name] || 0)
    return acc
  },
  {}
)).map(([name, count]) => ({ name, count }))

console.log(result)
```

Here's the same solution broken into multiple parts to make it easier to understand:

```js
const data = [{name:'v1', count:1}, {name:'v1', count:1}, {name:'v2', count:1}, {name:'v2', count:1}]

const r1 = data.reduce(
  (acc, { name, count }) => {
    acc[name] = count + (acc[name] || 0)
    return acc
  },
  {}
)
console.log(r1)

const r2 = Object.entries(r1)
console.log(r2)

const r3 = r2.map(([name, count]) => ({ name, count }))
console.log(r3)
```

Comment: If a list of keys that are to be checked to add up the count are given, how can I replicate this behaviour. say array of [name, group] is given, and if the values corresponding to these keys are same, then the counts are added.